# script set command output to variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, eval

I'm writing a simple script that prompts the user for information and saves it as a variable to be passed as arguments in another command. One of the variables stores a path which may include a space. Using the `read` command's `-r` tag, the path is retrieved as 'raw' input, ignoring the backslash escape character.

For example:

```
read -p "Enter checksum algorithm number (1, 224, 256, 384, 512, 512224, 412256): " -a shaa
read -p "Enter a file path: " -re shapath
```

<s>The problem is I cannot figure out how to run the command with those arguments without it reading the escape character.</s> Solved per @heemayl

I then need to store the output or return value of the command as another variable.

For example:

```
foo=$(shasum -a "$shaa" "$shapath")
```

However, when I `echo $foo` I do not get the expected output of `shasum -a "$shaa" "$shapath"`, but instead get `shasum: /.../checksum.dmg`

I was able to get it to work by using `eval` and piping it into `var` as shown below:

```
eval shasum -a $sha $shapath > val
```

I've read I should avoid `eval` at all costs and it does not allow me to continue forward with the script.

Comment: Per @heemayl's suggestion, I have edited the question to better reflect the big picture question which was previously only evident in the subsequent comments.

Comment: @John I've further edited the original question as to avoid duplicating the previously asked question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes:

```
shasum -a "$sha" "$shapath"
```

The variables will be expanded as single arguments irrespective of any spaces in the values.

Comment: I should have included that I need to store the return value of `shasum -a "$sha" "$shapath"` in another variable. Which is why I have been using `eval`

Comment: @andrewkeithly Use command substitution then `foobar=$(shasum -a "$sha" "$shapath")`

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work. If I `echo foobar` it gives me `shasum: ~/../checksum.dmg:`

Comment: @andrewkeithly `~` wont be expanded, you will have to use `eval` in that case or use other tricks..try using full path e.g. `/home/foo/....`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @heemayl. Unfortunately, using the full path still gave me `shasum: /.../checksum.dmg` upon using `echo`

Comment: @andrewkeithly your question is a bit value, could you please edit your question and add what you actually want at the end and what you have right now?